# Is there any software which is tender on RAM, and can remotely shut down my PC?

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, remote-desktop

Is there any software which is tender on RAM, and can remotely shut down my PC? I am using lubuntu 13.10

Comment: What's wrong with SSH-ing in and issuing init 0 or shutdown?

Comment: What do you mean by tender?

Answer (score 1):

**Of course there is**, but you will need an active daemon (it's like a Windows service) in your controllable machine.
It can require time, i'm writing to you a brief explanation:

1. A discrete solution for experienced users is the [Knockd daemon](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock/), which can be used to elaborate the probes sent to your computer. You should associate the `shutdown -hP now` command in the config file (command = `shutdown -hP now` **OR** command = `/usr/bin/shutdown -hP now`).
   **Be aware that this can also allow an attacker to shutdown/attack your machine** if you don't change the default knocks in the config file. Read the manual on the website **before** installing this software. You can install it by writing in a terminal (xterm is OK) `apt-get install knockd` or with your packed manager (search `knockd` or 'knockd daemon').
2. An more obvious solution is to use an ssh server software.
   This is a *secure*, well tested and common solution; you'll find hundred of guides about **openssh**-server. 
   If it isn't already installed, on a terminal (xterm is OK) execute: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.
   If the installation fails, check your connection or use Synaptics (or your preferred packet manager) to find a different ssh server in the repository.
   After the installation, reboot and execute in the term `pa -A|grep ss` to know if ssh is active, if not let us know and we'll solve.
   In the remote computer (the client) install [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (*suggested* for Windows/NT users) or [one of those ssh client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) and obtain the IP of the controllable computer (the active server) by visiting a [specialized website](http://www.whatismyip.com/) from it (you can use the no-IP service with the apposite software to obtain a dynamic domain; you can use it like an IP, but you'll need to keep it updated).
   After this procedure connect with your client software and issue the shutdown command. If it doesn't shutdown let us know and we'll solve.
   Be aware that you must keep the ssh server updated (always do the distro security updates!) and well protected with a password/certificate.
3. If you can't use one of the above methods and you want an easy solution, use the common **RealVNC** or an equivalent proprietary software. Please note that there are also many easy-to-use but less common open source software for remote controlling a PC.
   Those software **will** consume more resources, more bandwidth and have more security vulnerabilities than the softwares suggested in the first two points, because are remote controlling software.

Remember: there is no pre-installed/pre-configured remote control software to do what you ask to do, because any control software can weak the system security if not used properly.

I hope I'm usefull, but this is not the place to insert a full guide.
If you need help with one of the methods comment down here and you'll be helped.

Have a nice experience.